# Clang tidy doesn't work properly for static member variable

Tags: c++, clang, clang-tidy

I am running clang-tidy for my project. Here are the relevant naming options from my .clang-tidy file:

```
- key:             readability-identifier-naming.ClassMemberCase # e.g., int myClassMember_
  value:           camelBack
- key:             readability-identifier-naming.ClassMemberSuffix # e.g., int myClassMember_
  value:           _
- key:             readability-identifier-naming.GlobalConstantCase # e.g., int MyGlobalConstant (please don't make globals)
  value:           CamelCase
- key:             readability-identifier-naming.IgnoreMainLikeFunctions # Doesn't apply clang checks to main() args
  value:           1
- key:             readability-identifier-naming.MacroDefinitionCase # e.g., #define MY_MACRO="PleaseDon'tUseMacrosAnywhere"
  value:           UPPER_CASE
- key:             readability-identifier-naming.MacroDefinitionIgnoredRegexp
  value:           '^[A-Z]+(_[A-Z]+)*_$'
- key:             readability-identifier-naming.MemberCase # e.g., int myMember_ = 42;
  value:           CamelCase
- key:             readability-identifier-naming.MemberSuffix # e.g., int myMember_ = 42;
  value:           _
- key:             readability-identifier-naming.ParameterCase # e.g., void MyFunction(int parameter, int anotherParam);
  value:           camelBack
- key:             readability-identifier-naming.StaticConstantCase # e.g., static const std::string s_myStaticConstant = "I hope this works!"
  value:           camelBack
- key:             readability-identifier-naming.StaticConstantPrefix # e.g., static const std::string s_myStaticConstant = "I hope this works!"
  value:           s_
- key:             readability-identifier-naming.StaticVariableCase # e.g., static std::string s_myStaticVar = "I hope this works!"
  value:           camelBack
- key:             readability-identifier-naming.StaticVariablePrefix # e.g., static std::string s_myStaticVar = "I hope this works!"
  value:           s_
- key:             readability-identifier-naming.StructCase # e.g., struct MyStruct { ... };
  value:           CamelCase
- key:             readability-identifier-naming.VariableCase # e.g., int myVariable = 10;
  value:           camelBack
```

Unfortunately, clang tidy turns my static class member variables into `sMyVariable_` instead of `s_myVariable_`. It seems as if the options for class members are overriding the options for static variables:

```
warning: invalid case style for class member 's_myVariable_' [readability-identifier-naming]
int MyClass::s_myVariable_ = 1;
```

Is there any way to have the static naming rules prioritized over the member naming rules? Thanks!

Example code:

```
class MyClass{
   static int s_myVariable_; // Clang-tidy doesn't like this
};
```

Comment: Cold you show the code, in other words a [mcve]?

Comment: I added the code snippet. It is very trivial though, I don't see how it's any more helpful.

Comment: It works perfectly. `int s_myVariable_` is not a static member variable.

Comment: Sorry, typo when I pulled out the relevant bit of code. I've fixed it. Are you sure it's working for you? Clang-tidy is very clear on the rules it's deciding to enforce here, and it keeps correcting my variable to sMyVariable_

Comment: Your talk about reformatting has me thinking that you mean "clang format" rather than "clang tidy"..?.

Comment: It looks like for some reason there is no definitions for static member variables... StaticXXX refers to non-member variables only.

Comment: @sklott I noticed this, which is what I think the problem is. Seems like there might not be a super clean way to enforce this rule for static members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a hard time finding this in the [documentation](https://releases.llvm.org/8.0.0/tools/clang/tools/extra/docs/clang-tidy/checks/readability-identifier-naming.html#cmdoption-arg-classmembercase) as well.  It appears that static member variable *readability-identifier-naming* styles are defined with *ClassMemberCase*, *ClassMemberPrefix*, and *ClassMemberSuffix*.

For your desired formatting

```cpp
class MyClass{
   static int s_myVariable_; // Clang-tidy doesn't like this
};
```

the `CheckOptions` field of the .clang-tidy file would have the follwing key/values:

```
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.ClassMemberPrefix,   value: s_  }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.ClassMemberCase,     value: camelBack  }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.ClassMemberSuffix,   value: _  }
```

Comment: Hi Marc, wouldn't this then prefix all class members with an `s_`, even non-static ones? This is undesired.

Comment: It did not for me.  As far as I can tell from the documentation linked above, `ClassMemberX` effects only the static member variables.  There are other styles defined by `MemberCaseX`, `PrivateMemberX`, `ProtectedMemberX`, etc.. which effect the other scoped member variables.  I am not sure if these somehow override `ClassMemberX`, or if they are separate styles entirely, but defining them should help get the formatting you're looking for.

Comment: Hi Marc, it seems like this works pretty well for me, except for the case when members are static constexpr. Do you have any tips for this?

Comment: I would look at either `ConstexprVariablePrefix` / `ConstexprVariableCase` or one of the `xConstantPrefix` / `xConstantCase' fields.  They are all set to "k" and "CamelCase" for me, so I'm not sure which one covers static constexpr.